# CloudFormation is not propagating stack-level tags for EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

As per the [AWS Cloudformation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html)
it is mentioned that Cloudformation automatically provides **stack-level** tags to resources.

> aws:cloudformation:logical-id
>   aws:cloudformation:stack-id
>   aws:cloudformation:stack-name

I could see that for resources like EC2, S3, etc.
But when it comes to EMR I couldn’t see those tags. I need `aws:cloudformation:stack-id` tag value, so that I can later identify stackId without any hustle.

**Isn’t it supported for EMR?**
If not what could be workaround? I need to add CF **stackId** using which I can easily identify the stack for other use.

Note: `aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --physical-resource-id j-XXXXXXXXXXX` this is not an option to get stackId because of not having enough IAM politics.

---

**How I'm creating EMR cluster:** I have one lambda which invokes CloudFormation using boto3, which then created the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I checked that on my EMR cluster and CloudFormation. **You are correct**. Tags are no where to be seen.

Could be oversight on AWS part, as they explicitly write in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html) that only EBS volumes don't have such tags:

> All stack-level tags, including **automatically created tags**, are propagated to resources that AWS CloudFormation supports. Currently, tags are not propagated to Amazon EBS volumes that are created from block device mappings.

The only **workaround** I can think of is to "manually" create such tags, e.g. using [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). Or as you are already using lambda, do it in your lambda after EMR cluster creation.

Comment: Find a workaround with Pseudo Parameters Reference [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-stackid)

Comment: spoke with the support, they are working on it introducing this feature to CF like other resource.

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti Thanks for letting me know. Hopefully they will AWS ill sort this out.